# JavaScript global replacement

Tags: javascript

I wanna perform a global replacement by using JavaScript String **replace()** Method.

Original string:

```
<image>imageURL</image>
```

Result:

```
<img src="imageURL" />
```

How to achieve it? It should be similar with below code, but i don't know how to write the expression. Thanks in advance.

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Comment: Are you converting XML to HTML? You should not use RegExp then.

Comment: Simple Sugestion: grab only `imageURL` and create your `<img>` tags with that imageURL!

Comment: Why are people downvoting man? I don't see any reason!

Comment: @user1708762 I didn't downvote but OP should probably have tried a bit harder to build a regex before asking.

Comment: Hi Pavlo, i'm not converting XML to HTML, it's just string replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler here, you can return

```
text.replace(/<image>([^<]+)<\/image>/ig,'<img src="$1"/>')
```

Note that I didn't try to check the validity of the URL. I think it's better not to do a partial bogus check here. `[^<]+` means "some characters that are not `<`". If you prefer, you may replace it with your URL checking regex.

Comment: Hi dystroy, thanks for your answer, it works fine, but another issue comes out, my **replaceURLWithHTMLLinks() function** also tries to replace image url, how to escape this?

Comment: @zizibj You seem to be making a complete transformer for one format to another one. This isn't trivial (and sometimes is best done using a parser). It seems similar to **[what I do here](http://dystroy.org/miaou/static/test_format.html)**. You should check it out.

Comment: Hi dystroy, thanks for sharing, gonna see how to make it work, great work.